# Bad practice to use same name for function and module in Python?

Tags: python, function, module, naming-conventions, naming

I am developing a program to perform a specific type of calculation. The program consists of a top level module that calls several lower level modules, as follows:

```
input_data = "somefile.csv"
intermediate_result = convert_units(input_data)
final_result = fit_parameters(intermediate_result)
plot_results(final_result )
```

Each lower level module just performs one task, so I defined a function in each one with the same name as the module itself. For instance, my "convert_units.py" module begins with: `def convert_units(input_data):`

Consequently, in my top level module I need to import this with the following code: `from convert_units import convert_units`.

This works perfectly fine, but it looks repetitive, which can be a sign of bad code. So I wanted to ask: Does anyone know if this breaks any convention, or if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Put all the functions in a single module.

Comment: array, bisect, pprint, random, dis, time, timeit, ... You're in good company.

Comment: Do all the submodules have only the one function? That seems to me like you should just put them all in the top-level module and dispense with submodules

Comment: Thank you for these comments, it is great to know that other reputable modules and functions use the same name. Based on this I am happy to keep this as is. Regarding the reason for not putting everything in a single module, the example in the question was a simplification to illustrate the concept. There are actually dozens of modules, and I may want to reuse some in future programs.